# Can we say $g(x)$ convergence to $0$ faster than $f(x)$?

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$

If
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}>1$$

Can we say  $g(x)$ convergence to $0$ "*faster*" than $f(x)$?

Comment: One says $g(x)$ converges to $0$ faster than $f(x)$ only if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \cfrac{g(x)}{f(x)} = 0$. Equivalently, if you replace $>1$ with $=\infty$ in your condition.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not. Take $f(x)=\frac{2}{x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Both functions tends to zero as $x$ tends to infinity and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{2}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}= 2 > 1$, but I won't say that $\frac{1}{x}$ converges to zero "faster" (by all means) than $\frac{2}{x}$.

Comment: İf limit ($\frac{100}{x}$ and  $\frac{1}{x}$ ) equal to $100$ ??

Comment: Yes, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{100/x}{1/x}=100$.

Comment: We can't say convergence to $0$?

Comment: It became hard for me to understand what are you asking about and what things are unclear to you. Obviously any mentioned functions ($\frac{1}{x}, \frac{2}{x}, \frac{100}{x}$) converges to $0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @Hasek, you should be saying 'I won't say that $\frac{1}{x}$ converges to zero "faster" (by all means) than $\frac{2}{x}$'

Comment: @mathworker21, oh, sorry, I hadn't reread my message before submitting and this is a real mistake of mine. Thank you very much, I have to edit my answer now.